# bootstrap carousel in xpages is not manually sliding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, carousel

I implemented the bootstrap carousel into my xpages and it works fine in automatic mode. But I am not able to manually switch the pictures (the hover stops also works well).

Below is the code which was created from my xpage. Ok, the id tags looks a little bit strange. The href's are computed...

```
<div id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel" class="carousel slide">
<div id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner" class="carousel-inner">
<div id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:0:Image" class="item active">
<img id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:0:image1" src="....jpg" alt="" class="viewphoto"></div>
<div id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:1:Image" class="item">
<img id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:1:image1" src="....jpg" alt="" class="viewphoto"></div>
<div id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:2:Image" class="item">
<img id="view:_id1:_id215:carousel_inner:2:image1" src="....jpg" alt="" class="viewphoto"></div>
</div>
<a id="view:_id1:_id215:cLeft" href="#view:_id1:_id215:carousel" class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev">&lt;</a>
<a id="view:_id1:_id215:cRight" href="#view:_id1:_id215:carousel" class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next">&gt;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

thats how the xpage code looks (as an additional info)

```
    <xp:panel id="carousel" styleClass="carousel slide">
        <xp:repeat id="carousel_inner" rows="30" value="#{view1}"
            var="cImages" styleClass="carousel-inner">

            <xp:panel id="Image">

                <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (sessionScope.carCount == 1){
                sessionScope.carCount = 2;
                        return "item active";
                    } else {
                        return "item"
                }}]]></xp:this.styleClass>

                <xp:image id="image1" styleClass="viewphoto">
                    <xp:this.url><![CDATA[#{javascript:getCImageHTML(cImages.getDocument(), "fnImage", "Image")}]]></xp:this.url>
                </xp:image>

                <xp:panel styleClass="carousel-caption" id="caption">
                    <h4>Thumbnaillabel header</h4>
                    <xp:label value="Aloha some description" id="label1"></xp:label>
                </xp:panel>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:repeat>

        <xp:link escape="true" id="cLeft" styleClass="carousel-control left"
            value="##{id:carousel}">
            <xp:this.text><![CDATA[<]]></xp:this.text>
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="data-slide" value="prev"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:link>

        <xp:link escape="true" id="cRight" styleClass="carousel-control right"
            value="##{id:carousel}">
            <xp:this.text><![CDATA[>]]></xp:this.text>
            <xp:this.attrs>
                <xp:attr name="data-slide" value="next"></xp:attr>
            </xp:this.attrs>
        </xp:link>
    </xp:panel>
```

So maybe someone have an idea. Or maybe it is not possible because of the computed id tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what the problem is. The ':' in the ID-Tags are the problem. The 'slide-prev/next' won't work with it because it's a special character in jQuery.

So I created a function which masquerades the colon with a backslash.

Now it works fine

Thanks
Armin

Comment: Care to share the function?

Comment: function x$(idTag){ 
 idTag = idTag.replace(/:/g, "\\\\:");
  return("#" + idTag);
}

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could see more of your code. Where in the document are you defining the following?

1. jquery.js
2. bootstrap.js
3. bootstrap-carousel.js
4. bootstrap.css

Also, is your carousel in a separate custom control from all your resource/js/css definitions? I wound up adding my jquery and bootstrap js as static definitions at the end of each of my components (I was losing some functionality otherwise, with jquery only taking effect on part of my page, in a single page app with xe:dynamicContent control).

Comment: Hi Eric, I added the jquery.js, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css in the xpage. The carousel is a seperate custom control, so I will check to put them directly into CC...